# The select element in html is not setting the width property to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="mb10 nav nav-pills nav-justified form-tabs hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <li class="tab-selector active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Information Services</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Transactions</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Changes/Additions</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Service Agencies</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Data Analysis</a></li>
  </ul>
  <select class="mb10 form-control visible-xs service-tabs" id="tab_selector">
            <option value="0">Information Services</option>
            <option value="1">Transactions</option>
            <option value="2">Changes/Additions</option>
      <option value="3">Login</option>
            <option value="4">Service Agencies</option>
            <option value="5">Data Analysis</option>
        </select>
  <div class="tab-content visible-xs">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Know Your Bhudhaar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bhu-Samacharam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Information on approved Layouts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History of Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rights on forest land</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub"><a href="#">Mutation</a><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="sublist">
            <li><a href="#">Agriculture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rural Property</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Urban Property</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Land Conversion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Division</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Grievances</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Name Change</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Mobile No.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Update Mobile No.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Government Departments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Agencies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Citizen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Meeseva</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meekosam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bhuseva Processing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Webland Vs SSLR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add more information on the OP not only a code sample

Comment: where have you set its width to 100% to get the output

Comment: do you want the select box to be 100% ?

`<select class="mb10 form-control visible-xs service-tabs" id="tab_selector" style="width:100%">`

Answer (score 0):

see snippet, if that what you meant.

```css
#tab_selector {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="mb10 nav nav-pills nav-justified form-tabs hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <li class="tab-selector active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Information Services</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Transactions</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Changes/Additions</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Service Agencies</a></li>
    <li class="tab-selector"><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Data Analysis</a></li>
  </ul>
  <select class="mb10 form-control visible-xs service-tabs" id="tab_selector">
            <option value="0">Information Services</option>
            <option value="1">Transactions</option>
            <option value="2">Changes/Additions</option>
      <option value="3">Login</option>
            <option value="4">Service Agencies</option>
            <option value="5">Data Analysis</option>
        </select>
  <div class="tab-content visible-xs">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Know Your Bhudhaar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bhu-Samacharam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Information on approved Layouts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History of Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rights on forest land</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub"><a href="#">Mutation</a><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="sublist">
            <li><a href="#">Agriculture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rural Property</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Urban Property</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Land Conversion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Division</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Grievances</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Name Change</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Mobile No.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Update Mobile No.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Government Departments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Agencies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Citizen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Meeseva</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meekosam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bhuseva Processing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Webland Vs SSLR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have alredy tried but not working. My requirment is it should be 100% width in mobile devices                                                                                                         .service-tabs {
 background-color: #006c2e !important;
 color: white !important;
 display: block !important;
 font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
}
.tabbable {
 border: 4px solid #006c2e !important;
}

.tab-content ul li a {
 color: black !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
}

Comment: its working fine in my localhost but not working in production

Comment: clear your browser cache and see for any other css property should not override it.

Answer (score 0):

use `<select class="mb10 form-control visible-xs service-tabs" id="tab_selector" style="width: -webkit-fill-available;">`

OR

```
 <select class="mb10 form-control visible-xs service-tabs" id="tab_selector" style="width: 100%">
```

Style attribute added in `<select>` tag to define css.

Comment: everything is working fine in my local host but during production it is not working

Comment: Then there must be some other issue, try inspect element in browser and check, may be you could identify problem